# Polymer: making JSON ajax requests to NodeJS backend

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, polymer

I'm trying to test using NodeJS as a backend api for a Polymer front end. On the Polymer side, I have this iron-ajax element:

```
<iron-ajax 
  id='test-req' 
  url='http://localhost:9090/backend-test' 
  handle-as='text' 
  on-response='testRsp'
  body='{"data":"stuff"}'>
</iron-ajax>
```

The testRsp handler simply logs the response text to the console. On the backend, this is my route:

```
app.get('/backend-test', function(req, res){
    res.send(req.body)
    console.log(req.body)
}
```

As you can see, all it does is respond with the raw request, and log the request on the backend. Both sides as expected have the same result, but unfortunately the result is just `{}`.

Now, I also tried sending the json in via the params attribute instead of the body attribute of the iron-ajax element, and on the backend I used the deprecated req.param() function like so: `req.param('data')`, and that correctly prints out `stuff` on both the browser and the backend. However, since it is deprecated, I'm trying to avoid that method.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**: I figured this extra piece of info would be helpful. When I log `req.originalUrl` on the backend when passing the json in 'params', I get `/backend-test?data=stuff`. When passing in 'body', it's just `/backend-test`.

I also want to note that I have tried variations of the bodyParser middleware as well:

->`app.use(bodyParser.json())` (outcome as noted above)

->`app.use(bodyParser.text())` (same)

->not using bodyParser at all (prints `undefined` as expected based on the express docs)

->`app.use(bodyParser.text()); app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` (same output as json() and text(); taken from the [req.body docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body)).

**Edit2** Thanks AP. I have been putting the use statements before any route definitions, like so:

```
// Create Express object, enable CORS
var app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())

// Route definitions
app.post('/backend_test', function(req, res){
    res.json(req.body)
    console.log(req.body)

})

app.listen(9090, function() {
    console.log('App started, listening on port 9090')
})
```

I also updated my iron-ajax element to explicitly make a post rather than get, and set content type as json, but no dice. I'm still getting only `{}` out the other side:

```
<iron-ajax 
  id='test-req' 
  url='http://localhost:9090/backend_test' 
  content-type="json"
  method="post"
  handle-as='json' 
  on-response='testRsp'
  body='{"data":"stuff"}'>
</iron-ajax>
```

**Edit3** I found the mistake with my update, content-type needed to be `application/json`, not just `json`. That got it working finally. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your middleware should be initialized before your routes, and should somewhat resemble this:

```
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

In terms of the Polymer Implementation, if you are sending `JSON` data, according to the [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax) your element should also contain:

```
<iron-ajax content-type='json'>
```

There is also a [demo-repository](https://github.com/avdaredevil/Demo-Advanced_Web/tree/master/Demo-Start) that show's an example MEAN stack server running polymer as it's front-end. Which I believe ties into your question as well?

PS. [Youtube-Black](https://github.com/avdaredevil/Youtube-Black) is a more comprehensive example.

### Edit:

I just realized you're missing the `method` attribute on your Polymer element. Without that, you are sending a `GET` request! Make sure to use your element like so, in addition to your other props:

```
<iron-ajax content-type='json' method='post'>
```